# How can I define my Solidity contract as a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm making a simple app to act as a front end for a smart contract.  The contract has a public string attribute `message` which I expected to be able to access through `newContract.methods.message().call()`.

I defined an `onclick` call to a `showMessage()` function which should log the message attribute to the console, however when I click the button with the `onclick` event, I receive the error messages at the bottom of this post.

The checks below the instantiation of the new contract object indicate that the type is not undefined, but I still receive an `undefined` error anyway.

***Edit:***
Removed extraneous ABI parts and added smart contract source code.

The issue appears to be with the scope of the `newContract` object.  Even though it's declared with `var`, it isn't accessible through the global `window` object inside the `showMessage()` function.  What is the correct scope?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.3.5/web3.min.js" integrity="sha512-S/O+gH5szs/+/dUylm15Jp/JZJsIoWlpSVMwT6yAS4Rh7kazaRUxSzFBwnqE2/jBphcr7xovTQJaopiEZAzi+A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            let web3js;

            function startApp() {            
                var address = "...";
                const jsoninterface = [
                
                    {
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "_newMessage",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "setMessage",
                        "outputs": [],
                        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                        "type": "function"
                    },
                   
                    {
                        "inputs": [],
                        "name": "message",
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ],
                        "stateMutability": "view",
                        "type": "function"
                    }
                ]
                var newContract = new web3js.eth.Contract(jsoninterface, address);
                if (typeof newContract === 'object' && typeof newContract !== 'undefined' && newContract !== null){
                    console.log("contract created")
                } else {
                    console.log("contract not created")
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {

                // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
                if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
                web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
                } else {
                    alert("Please install Metamask to continue");
                // Handle the case where the user doesn't have Metamask installed
                // Probably show them a message prompting them to install Metamask
                }

                // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
                startApp();
                console.log('startapp finished')
            })

            function showMessage(){
                var retval = window.newContract.methods.message().call();
                console.log(retval);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- the content goes here -->
        <button onclick="showMessage()">click here</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the output to the console:

```
contract created
startapp finished
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    at showMessage ((index):132)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):140)
showMessage @ (index):132
onclick @ (index):140
```

Below is the smart contract code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


contract HelloWorld {
    string public message = "Hello World";
    uint public counter = 0;
    
    function setMessage(string calldata _newMessage) public {
        message = _newMessage;
    }
    
    function incrementCounter() public {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue did turn out to be the scope of the contract variable, making the two changes indicated by arrows below allowed me to solve my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.3.5/web3.min.js" integrity="sha512-S/O+gH5szs/+/dUylm15Jp/JZJsIoWlpSVMwT6yAS4Rh7kazaRUxSzFBwnqE2/jBphcr7xovTQJaopiEZAzi+A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            let web3js;
 ---------> var newContract;
            function startApp() {            
                var address = "...";
                const jsoninterface = [
                
                    {
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "_newMessage",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "setMessage",
                        "outputs": [],
                        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                        "type": "function"
                    },
                   
                    {
                        "inputs": [],
                        "name": "message",
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ],
                        "stateMutability": "view",
                        "type": "function"
                    }
                ]
  ---------> window.newContract = new web3js.eth.Contract(jsoninterface, address);
                if (typeof newContract === 'object' && typeof newContract !== 'undefined' && newContract !== null){
                    console.log("contract created")
                } else {
                    console.log("contract not created")
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {

                // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
                if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
                web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
                } else {
                    alert("Please install Metamask to continue");
                // Handle the case where the user doesn't have Metamask installed
                // Probably show them a message prompting them to install Metamask
                }

                // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
                startApp();
                console.log('startapp finished')
            })

            function showMessage(){
                var retval = window.newContract.methods.message().call();
                console.log(retval);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- the content goes here -->
        <button onclick="showMessage()">click here</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ABI JSON defines a `setMessage()` function, but no `message` property (or a function). If you have the `message` property (or function) in your contract, it needs to be `external` or `public` in order to be readable from outside of the contract.

You'll also need to re-generate the ABI JSON after you've made the property or function external or public.